# How to switch Classes

Tags: python

```
class Book(object):
    def __init__(self, title):
        self.title = title

    def setCategory(self, category):
        self.category = category


class RomanceBook(Book):
    def __init__(self, title):
        super(RomanceBook, self).__init__(title)
        self.category = 'romance'

    def getTitle(self):
        return self.title.upper()


class FictionBook(Book):
    def __init__(self, title):
        super(FictionBook, self).__init__(title)
        self.category = 'fiction'

    def getTitle(self):
        return self.title.lower().replace(' ', '_')
```

Both `RomanceBook` and `FictionBook` classes inherit from the same `Book` class. Both classes have the `getTitle()` method which returns the book's title. The `RomanceBook` returns the title using the letter upper case while the `FictionBook` class returns the title using lower case:

```
romance_book = RomanceBook('Love Story')
print romance_book, romance_book.getTitle() 

fiction_book = FictionBook('Star Wars')
print fiction_book.getTitle()
```

This prints:

```
<__main__.RomanceBook object at 0x108d37610> LOVE STORY
<__main__.FictionBook object at 0x108d37650> star_wars
```

Now I go ahead and change the `category` attribute of the `fiction_book` instance from 'fiction' to `romance`.

```
fiction_book.setCategory('romance')
```

It would be great if the `fiction_book` instance would switch its class from `FictionBook` to `RomanceBook` at the same time the `category` attribute is changed. It would then inherit all the behaviors of the `RomanceBook` acting like a "real" romance book. If I would switch its category to "fiction" it would switch its class again and so on.

How could we modify the example code to make it work?

Comment: So if I understand well, OP means is there a way could an instance change it's class such as `self = RomanceBook()`.

Comment: Each object has a `__class__` attribute which can be changed but this is generally a bad idea. Think about why you need here two different classes at all.

Comment: If switching a Class for the instance is a bad idea please illustrate how a similar effect could be achieved.

Comment: What you're asking isn't how classes are designed to work. Once created, an integer is always an integer, a string is always a string, and a RomanceBook is always a RomanceBook. You should either subclass, or have a "category" attribute, but not both. Or, create a converter function which takes a book of one class and returns a new book of a different class with all of the attributes of the original book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably better ways to do what you want than class switching (maybe something like the [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)) but if you really want to do this, you could assign to the instances `__class__`:

```
class Book(object):
    def __init__(self, title):
        self.title = title

    def setCategory(self, category):
        self.category = category
        self.__class__ = classes[category] # IMPORTANT


class RomanceBook(Book):
    def __init__(self, title):
        super(RomanceBook, self).__init__(title)
        self.category = 'romance'

    def getTitle(self):
        return self.title.upper()


class FictionBook(Book):
    def __init__(self, title):
        super(FictionBook, self).__init__(title)
        self.category = 'fiction'

    def getTitle(self):
        return self.title.lower().replace(' ', '_')

classes = {
  'romance': RomanceBook, # IMPORTANT
  'fiction': FictionBook, # IMPORTANT
}
```

Or, if you want to automatically add to `classes` with a metaclass:

```
classes = {}

class BookMetaclass(type):
  def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
          new_class = type.__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
          if name != "Book":
            classes[new_class.category] = new_class

          return new_class

class Book(object, metaclass=BookMetaclass):
    def __init__(self, title):
        self.title = title

    def setCategory(self, category):
        self.category = category
        self.__class__ = classes[category]

...
```

Example with the strategy pattern:

```
class Book(object):
    title_funcs = {
      'romance': lambda title: title.upper(),
      'fiction': lambda title: title.lower().replace(' ', '_'),
    }

    def __init__(self, category, title):
        self.category = category
        self.title = title

    def setCategory(self, category):
        self.category = category

    def getTitle(self):
      return self.title_funcs[self.category](self.title)
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in different variations but basically it is about delegating methods:

```
class RomanceBookSupport:

    @staticmethod
    def getTitle(book):
        return book.title.upper()


class FictionBookSupport:

    @staticmethod
    def getTitle(book):
        return book.title.lower().replace(' ', '_')


SUPPORTMAP = {
    'romance' : RomanceBookSupport,
    'fiction' : FictionBookSupport
}


class Book(object):
    def __init__(self, title):
        self.title = title

    def setCategory(self, category):
        self.category = category

    def getTitle(self):
        return SUPPORTMAP[self.category].getTitle(self)


romance_book = Book('Love Story')
romance_book.setCategory('romance')
print romance_book, romance_book.getTitle() 

fiction_book = Book('Star Wars')
fiction_book.setCategory('fiction')
print fiction_book.getTitle()

fiction_book.setCategory('romance')
print fiction_book.getTitle()
```

Comment: Wouldn't you have to pass `self` as an argument on the last line?

Comment: Unfortunately your code does not work. Please fix the error and re-post your answer.

Comment: @alphanumeric This code was mainly meant as a sketch how to write it. It works now (Python 2.6).

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you want, by extracting the getTitle method to the base class and dynamically decide which strategy should use:

```
class Book(object):
    def __init__(self, title):
        self.title = title

    def setCategory(self, category):
        self.category = category

    def getTitle(self):

        if self.category == 'romance':
            return self.title.upper()
        elif self.category == 'fiction':
            return self.title.lower().replace(' ', '_')
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError()


class RomanceBook(Book):
    def __init__(self, title):
        super(RomanceBook, self).__init__(title)
        self.category = 'romance'


class FictionBook(Book):
    def __init__(self, title):
        super(FictionBook, self).__init__(title)
        self.category = 'fiction'


romance_book = RomanceBook('Love Story')
print(romance_book.getTitle())

fiction_book = FictionBook('Star Wars')

print(fiction_book.getTitle())

fiction_book.setCategory('romance')

print(fiction_book.getTitle())
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use a mapping library between the two; [GitHub](https://github.com/marazt/object-mapper)

```
from mapper.object_mapper import ObjectMapper


class Book(object):
    def __init__(self, title):
        self.title = title

    def setCategory(self, category):
        self.category = category


class RomanceBook(Book):
    def __init__(self, title=None):
        super(RomanceBook, self).__init__(title)
        self.category = 'romance'

    def getTitle(self):
        return self.title.upper()


class FictionBook(Book):
    def __init__(self, title=None):
        super(FictionBook, self).__init__(title)
        self.category = 'fiction'

    def getTitle(self):
        return self.title.lower().replace(' ', '_')


def new_book_type(book: Book, new_type):
    mapper = ObjectMapper()
    mapper.create_map(type(book), new_type)
    return mapper.map(book, new_type)

romance_book = RomanceBook('Love Story')
print (romance_book, romance_book.getTitle() )

fiction_book = FictionBook('Star Wars')
print(fiction_book, fiction_book.getTitle())

romantic_star_wars = new_book_type(fiction_book, RomanceBook)
print(romantic_star_wars, romantic_star_wars.getTitle())
```

yields

```
<__main__.RomanceBook object at 0x7fdf6e69ac50> LOVE STORY
<__main__.FictionBook object at 0x7fdf6d1a0a90> star_wars
<__main__.RomanceBook object at 0x7fdf6d1a0b00> STAR WARS
```